# 'const command=require' throwing an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

This is the code-

```
for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    commands.push(command.data.toJSON());
```

The second line is trying to connect to file- /commands/hi.js

This is what hi.js contains

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('Hi')
        .setDescription('Get introduced to the bot'),
    async execute(interaction) {
        await interaction.reply('Hi I am Herote bot I was created by a Dog names barood /help for commands');
    },
};
```

And this is the error

```
    throw this.error;
    ^

ExpectedConstraintError: Invalid string format
    at Object.run (C:\Users\ranja\Desktop\Discord bot\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:1549:64)
    at C:\Users\ranja\Desktop\Discord bot\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:113:66
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at StringValidator.parse (C:\Users\ranja\Desktop\Discord bot\node_modules\@sapphire\shapeshift\dist\index.js:113:29)
    at validateName (C:\Users\ranja\Desktop\Discord bot\node_modules\@discordjs\builders\dist\index.js:819:17)
    at MixedClass.setName (C:\Users\ranja\Desktop\Discord bot\node_modules\@discordjs\builders\dist\index.js:895:5)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ranja\Desktop\Discord bot\commands\Hi.js:5:4)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1213:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1037:32) {
  constraint: 's.string.regex',
  given: 'Hi',
  expected: 'expected /^[\\p{Ll}\\p{Lm}\\p{Lo}\\p{N}\\p{sc=Devanagari}\\p{sc=Thai}_-]+$/u.test(expected) to be true'
}
```

It was supposed to just run the application after connecting but I am getting this error. I am using Node.js/npm modules/Discord.js latest version of each

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting this specific error is you are trying to capitalize the command name which with slash commands is not possible. Also a good thing to note is that you cannot capitalize command options either.

Just change it to this:

```
const { SlashCommandBuilder } = require('discord.js');

module.exports = {
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('hi')
        .setDescription('Get introduced to the bot'),
    async execute(interaction) {
        await interaction.reply('Hi I am Herote bot I was created by a Dog names barood /help for commands');
    },
};
```